# Installing Vapor on macOS without needing Homebrew

Tags: swift, vapor

I am trying to get a Swift Vapor project started. Following the guide [here](https://docs.vapor.codes/2.0/getting-started/install-on-macos/), it seems that Homebrew is the only option. I already have MacPorts and prefer it in many ways to Homebrew. Unfortunately there is no port for Vapor, so I went for the SPM installation that Vapor people describe [here](https://docs.vapor.codes/2.0/getting-started/manual/). I had previous success with Kitura, so I thought why not with Vapor. Well, when you go and build your project, you get

```
$ swift build

[... build stuff ...]

note: you may be able to install ctls using your system-packager:

    brew install ctls

[... more build stuff ...]

<module-includes>:1:9: note: in file included from <module-includes>:1:
#import "shim.h"
    ^
[... more like that ...]

  /Users/morpheu5/web/vizex/api/.build/checkouts/crypto.git-7980259129511365902/Sources/Crypto/Cipher/Cipher+Method.swift:1:8: error: could not build Objective-C module 'CTLS'
import CTLS
    ^
<unknown>:0: error: build had 1 command failures
error: exit(1):/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift-build-tool -f /Users/morpheu5/web/vizex/api/.build/debug.yaml
```

Apparently you really need this `ctls` package, and the only way of getting it appears to be through Homebrew/Tap.

I really don't want or need Homebrew, so how do I get to the bottom of this? I'd really like to give Vapor a try.

Comment: AFAIK, Vapor is installed via Swift Package Manager. Although the command line tools are quite handy, they aren't mandatory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obligatory 1: installing Homebrew is the easiest way. If you then decide you don't want Homebrew, it uninstalls quite neatly.

Obligatory 2: using a Linux VM is the second easiest way.

But to answer your question and manually install `CTLS`:

1. Make sure you have the libraries for `LibreSSL` or `OpenSSL` installed (using MacPorts, presumably)
2. Download the latest [release](https://github.com/vapor/ctls/releases) of `CTLS`.
3. From the release archive, rename `macos.pc` to `ctls.pc` and then edit it using a text editor. Change the paths to point to your LibreSSL/OpenSSL installation.
4. Move the edited `ctls.pc` into your `$PKG_CONFIG_PATH`.

I have tested this and it works for me, with the caveat that I installed `LibreSSL` using Homebrew so I don't know where MacPorts will put it.

Comment: My only problem with Homebrew is that I still prefer MacPorts and I'd hate for them to step on each other's toes. Thanks for your detailed answer :)